# Search for files using a date variable within the string search

Tags: string, variables, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am currently trying to search for the files within GAS according to today's date (which is formatted as a string), but I can't seem to get the syntax right to escape the search string.

My file titles are "Customers - dd-MM-yyyy", "Customers - dd-MM-yyyy-1", "Customers - dd-MM-yyyy-2" and so on. Some days only have one file, and therefore do not have the -1 or -2 extensions.

Variations that I have tried:

```
var TodayDate =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1", "dd-MM-yyyy"); //Get today's date
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Customers" and title contains TodayDate');
```

And:

```
var TodayDate =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1", "dd-MM-yyyy"); //Get today's date
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Customers" and title contains '+TodayDate);
```

The below code works correctly if I only have one file, without the -1 or -2 extensions:

```
var TodayDate =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1", "dd-MM-yyyy"); //Get today's date
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Customers '+TodayDate);
```

I've also tried using some form of .* notation around the TodayDate, but had trouble understanding regexp as a wildcard.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching by a date string, which is still a string, so it must be quoted, just like the string Customers:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Customers" and title contains "'+TodayDate+'"');
```